# Как сгруппировать массив объектов с условием?

Tags: javascript

У меня допустим 3 объекта

> {
>   id: 1,
>   group: 1,
>   sub: 0,
>   }

Сейчас я использую

```js
var a = names.reduce((acc, c) => ((acc[c.group] ? acc[c.group].push(c) : acc[c.group] = [c]), acc), {});
```

Т.е сейчас массив группируется исходя только из поля group, я не понимаю как сделать, что бы он группировал по условию. Если sub не пусто - он создает группу с именем саб, если саб пусто то он выполняет то что уже написано(группирует по group)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let names = [
  { id: 1, group: 1, sub: 0, },  
  { id: 2, group: 1, sub: 5, },  
  { id: 3, group: 2, sub: 0, },
];

var a = names.reduce((acc, c) => {
  var grp = c.sub || c.group;
  acc[grp] ? acc[grp].push(c) : (acc[grp] = [c]);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log( a );
```