# Последовательное выполнение кода в блоке then

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Как последовательно выполнить сначала создание таблицы, а затем вывести ее в консоль?

```
directory.findAll({raw: true})                  // Запрос ко всей таблице
      .then(tables => {
        var table = tables.reduce((acc, n) => {
          const g = n.subBranch || n.branch;
          (acc[g] = acc[g] || []).push(n);
          return acc;
console.log(table);
        },{});
      })
    });
```

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1053172

Comment: нет, не забыл...

Comment: ну я вообще не тестил твой ответ, потому что нашел раньше ответ в другом месте и раньше, но если это важно я поставил)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var table = tables.reduce((acc, n) => {
      ...
      return acc;
    }, {});
    console.log(table);
```

Comment: а разве он не будет выполняться асинхронно?

Comment: @ЮраГорячев Кто - "он"?

Comment: консоль лог разве не будет выполняться до формирования таблицы

Comment: @ЮраГорячев функция `reduce` - не асинхронная.